# Store JSONArrayRequest response in Android Studio

Tags: android, variables, request

Good morning! I've been a lot of days searching for an answer similar to this but I couldn't find it, so here I am.

In Android Studio, I've did a function which has a jsonArrayRequest request, which looks like this:

```
private String requestCoursesInfo() {
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.context);

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest= new JsonArrayRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            COURSES_URL,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray coursesJsonArray) {
                    String name;
                    ArrayList<HashMap> coursesBasicInfoList = new ArrayList<>();

                    try {
                        for (int i=0; i < coursesJsonArray.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject courseInfo = coursesJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            name = courseInfo.getString("name");

                            //ArrayList to group all the info
                            HashMap<String, String> currentCourseInfoList = new HashMap<>();

                            currentCourseInfoList.put("name", name);
                            coursesBasicInfoList.add(currentCourseInfoList);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        //Do something with error
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                    // Do something when error occurred
                }
            }
    ){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

            return params;
        }
    };

    // Add JsonObjectRequest to the RequestQueue
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    return "courses";
}
```

The thing is, as you can see, once I have the response I build a HashMap with the key **name** and value of the name from the response and I put it all in **coursesBasicInfoList** ArrayList.

The thing is, this variable (coursesBasicInfoList) is never accessible from outside the request and what I want is to be able to put this arraylist in the "return" that you can see at the end of the function.

I know the request is asynchronous but I suppose it has to be some way to store this data from the response to use it in other methods, isn't it?

Thank you!

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/how-to-get-data-from-any-asynchronous-operation-in-android) can help you out ?

Comment: I've tried it and it works in their way! But at the end I have a function which calls the Override and the response is within the Override, I can't take it out so I'm in the same situation..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LiveData` to solve synchronization problem in asynchronous call like `volley`.

```
private MutableLiveData<ArrayList<HashMap>> requestCoursesInfo() {
    MutableLiveData<ArrayList<HashMap>> mutableCoursesBasicInfoList = new MutableLiveData<>();
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.context);

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest= new JsonArrayRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            COURSES_URL,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray coursesJsonArray) {
                    String name;
                    ArrayList<HashMap> coursesBasicInfoList = new ArrayList<>();

                    try {
                        for (int i=0; i < coursesJsonArray.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject courseInfo = coursesJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            name = courseInfo.getString("name");

                            //ArrayList to group all the info
                            HashMap<String, String> currentCourseInfoList = new HashMap<>();

                            currentCourseInfoList.put("name", name);
                            coursesBasicInfoList.add(currentCourseInfoList);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        //Do something with error
                    }

                    //post your result in LiveData
                    mutableCoursesBasicInfoList.postValue(coursesBasicInfoList);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                    // Do something when error occurred
                }
            }
    ){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

            return params;
        }
    };

    // Add JsonObjectRequest to the RequestQueue
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

    //Return MutableLiveData<ArrayList<HashMap>> 
    return mutableCoursesBasicInfoList;
}
```

And the observe the LiveData from your Activity/Fragment like below:

```
requestCoursesInfo().observe(this, new Observer<ArrayList<HashMap>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(ArrayList<HashMap> hashMaps) {
        //Do your operation here with ArrayList<HashMap>
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, that seems cool! But the thing is that in the fragment I call the function through Courses.getBasicInfo() and inside this class method I call the requestCoursesInfo() (in your example) so at the end I have an override method which has the function whithin but I can't return it to the original place where I've called it because I can't take it out from there...